# If $e^{iux_n}$ converges for $u\in\mathbb{R}$, $x_n$ converge to a finite limit

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

> Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $e^{iux_n}$ converges as $n\to\infty$ for almost all $u\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $x_n$ converges to a finite limit.

I know a proof by probability theory (Protter's "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations"), but I want to show this theorem by analysis way. I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $e^{iu(x_n-x_m)}=\frac {e^{iux_n}}{e^{iux_m}} \to 1$ as $n, m \to \infty$ for almost all $u$. By DCT we get $\frac 1 2 \int_{-1}^{1} e^{iu(x_n-x_m)} du \to 1$. Take the real part and evaluate the integral. You will get $\frac {\sin (x_n-x_m)} {x_n-x_m} \to 1$. I will leave it to you to use some properties of $\sin x$ to show that $x_n-x_m\to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$. Thus $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, hence convergent.

Some details for the  last part: Let $\epsilon >0$ and consider the function $1-\frac {\sin x } x$ on $[\epsilon, \infty)$. This function is positive (why?) and continuous. It tends to $1$ as $ x \to \infty$. These facts imply that it has  a positive minimum. Call this minimum $\delta$. It follows that $ 1-\frac {\sin x} x \geq \delta$ whenever $x \geq \epsilon$. Hence $ 1-\frac {\sin x } x < \delta$ implies $x < \epsilon$. Take $x=|x_n-x_m|$ in this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\cos u(x_n-x_m)du \to 1$ implies $\frac{\sin(x_n-x_m)}{x_n-x_m}\to1$? I think last part of proof is problem that   suppose $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sin x_k}{x_k}=1$ then $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=0$. My idea is by uniqueness of limit, but I cannot show this. Could you tell me?

Comment: Do yo know how to calculate $\int_1^{1} \cos (au) du$? An anti-derivative for $\cos (au)$ is $\frac {\sin (au)} a$. Take $a=x_n-x_m$. For the last part I will add some details to the answer. @sate

Comment: Sorry, I was quite mistaken. yeah, it's simple integral calculation.

Comment: thank you for adding details of last part. yes, $f(x):=1-\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is positve because $\sin x<x$ on $x>0$. But, why there is positive minimum $\delta$? $[\epsilon,\infty)$ is not bounded. I'm sorry to bother you over and over.

Comment: If the infimum is $0$ then there is   sequence $x_n$ along which the function tends to $0$. But this sequence has to be bounded because the limit of the function  as $x \to \infty$ is $1$, not $0$. If $x_n$ is bounded by $M$ then the minimum  value of $f$ on $[0,M]$ will be $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now $f$ is defined on $[\epsilon,\infty)$, so not $[0,M]$, but $[\epsilon.M]$?

Comment: Yes, sorry! @sate

Comment: Thank you very much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

By Euler's formula, $$
e^{iux_n} = \cos ux_n + i\sin ux_n.
$$
Since $e^{iux_n}$ converges, both its real and imaginary parts must converge. Can you proceed from there?

Comment: thank you for your hint. So, simply by contradiction?

Comment: Some measure theory is required here.